# Grouping 2D points in minimum number of circles of varying radius

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I need to group a list of 2D points into a minimum number of circles. The criteria are as follows:

- Overlapping of circles is allowed but not recommended because the minimum number of circles is required.
- The default dataset assigned each point with a number that tells us the maximum radius of a circle that covers it.
- So the radius of a resultant circle depends on the points that it covers. If a circle contains multiple points, its radius must be the smallest number.
- All points must be grouped, even if a circle contains only 1 point.
- The required output is only the coordinates for the centres of all circles.

Example of the ideal grouping result (not from my flawed brute-force search):

[image]

Sample input and expected output:

```
[pt_x pt_y radius]=[[ 1 20 12],   #pt 1
                    [ 3 21 11],   #pt 2
                    [ 7 13 10],   #pt 3
                    [15 13 10],   #pt 4
                    [10  6 10],   #pt 5
                    [17  6  6],   #pt 6
                    [19  5  7],   #pt 7
                    [26 23  7],   #pt 8
                    [24 26  8],   #pt 9
                    [26 27  6],   #pt 10
                    [26 30 10],   #pt 11
                    [36  9 13],   #pt 12
                    [48 25 11],   #pt 13
                    [49 10 14],   #pt 14
                    [35 23 12],   #pt 15
                    [42 17 11],   #pt 16
                    [49 27  3]]   #pt 17

[cir_x cir_y]=[[ 7 13],   #circle 1 contains pts 1-5 with radius of 10
               [20  4],   #circle 2 contains pts 6-7 with radius of 6
               [26 27],   #circle 3 contains pts 8-11 with radius of 6
               [42 17],   #circle 4 contains pts 12-16 with radius of 11
               [50 29]]   #circle 5 contains pt 17 with radius of 3
```

The radius varies with the location of point xy, but it is not a function derived from xy (it is the range that can be covered by a sensor at point xy).

I tried to use a brute-force search (pseudocode below) by assuming the centres of all resultant circles must be picked from the given points (it doesn't necessarily need to be).

```matlab
sort input point list according to their given radius (column 3)
i=1
while input point list is not empty
   centre of ith circle = input point with smallest given radius
   radius of ith circle = smallest given radius
   remove input point with smallest given radius
   find distance of all points to the centre of ith circle
   remove any point with distance < radius of ith circle
   i=i+1
end
```

The result was not minimal and some circles overlapped one another. This approach is flawed because, by forcing the centres to be the given points, some points that can be covered in one circle may end up in separated circles (see below).

[image]

Is there any clustering/covering algorithm better suits my application?

I'm more concerned with efficiency rather than finding the global minimum because I need to implement the algorithm in a real-time system that may involve thousands or more data points. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can always cluster all of the points in one circle. Are there any other constraints?

Comment: The radius depends on the points. Each point corresponds to a unique radius. So if the smallest radius of all points is large enough to cover all points, then yes one circle is enough. But this will never be the case because I need to cover a space much larger than all radius.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. How does a point determine a radius? How does that relate to the bottom circle in your example (the one with 2 points) and the circle at the top right with one point?

Comment: Each point is assigned with a default radius at the start. For the top right and bottom circles, they contain only a few points because the big circles next to them are not big enough to cover these points. So these leftovers are grouped into another circle (again its radius is given by the points).

Comment: You have to explain "Each point corresponds to a unique radius" better.  At the very least, don't you have to tell us what these "unique radius" values are?

Comment: That seems to indicate that all of the final circles will have a point at their center?

Comment: Does this means some of the dots must be centres?

Comment: Not necessarily. The image was just a sketch of what I imagined the result would be. I assumed it would be easier if some points are used as centres.

Comment: Can you give an example of input values and expected output values?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand `The default dataset assigned each point with a unique number, which tells us the radius of circle that can cover it.` but can I think of it this way: for n sample dots, a maximum circle radius of r, find coordinates of circles and radius, when quantity of circles q is the smallest?

Comment: Or could you put the function which assign each dot with a radius value here? appreciate it.

Comment: The radius of each circle should be the smallest assigned number (third column of input) among all the points that it covers. The radius varies with xy coordinate, but it is not a function of xy (it is the range that can be covered by a sensor at point xy).

Comment: I think this is a "covering problem", not a "clustering problem", if that observation is worth anything...

Comment: I think it might be clearer if you said that "The default dataset assigned each point with a number that tells us the **maximum** radius of a circle that covers it." I'm also unclear as to whether the covering circle must be centered on one of the given points, although your diagram seems to indicate that it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I also added a figure to show why a circle shouldn't be centred at the given point.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have. It's not complete but maybe it will help. My brain is too tired tonight to do better:

I think you can create a tree where every level you go deeper is placing a circle, like a tree of board game states where every edge is a move. In this case the move is drawing a circle. The root indicates 0 circles, level one is 1 circle, etc.

For a given node, you can find the children by going through each point pair where both points are not in a circle, and both points are within their radius numbers. I still don't understand the requirements around picking the smallest radius, but let's set aside that for the moment.

<del>For every point pair a, b, you can draw 2 circles (or possibly up to 4 depending on the radius rules). You can draw a circle with a on the edge and the center on the line connecting a and b, or you can draw a circle with b on the edge and the center on the same line.</del>
Actually, I'm not sure this is correct. For example it may be better to draw more circles, like 2 with `a` and `b` on the edges. Also, I think the rule that I'm missing probably matters here...

So for every node, if you have `x` remaining points outside of circles, you can create a child of that node for each of the circle options times 2 (or possibly more) that you could draw. Once you've done that, you also remove from the playing field any points that got gobbled up by circles along the way.

Then, you're left with a tree of all possible circle combinations. You can then do a depth-first search to find the smallest one. The way I've described makes it sound like you have to generate the full tree ahead of time, you can do it as part of the search. This would save memory, but it sounds like maybe it's not a big enough problem to matter anyway.

Ultimately, this is somewhat of a brute-force effort, and there are probably several opportunities to make this faster. For example, once you've found a candidate solution with 4 circles, then for the rest of your depth-first search you only need to dig down to level 3 (cause you won't find any smaller solutions at levels >=4). There may be other optimizations.

So, hopefully that is worth something. As I said, I'm still fuzzy on the "smallest radius" requirements, my brain is too tired tonight.

Comment: I thought of using a brute-force search but it may not be efficient enough for my application, which may involve processing thousands of points in real time.

Comment: Not authoritative or anything but my intuition is  that with this problem the optimum algorithm may be brute force + some optimizations. If it's real time it might help to explain how the batches of data are coming in in real time. If every batch you get is related to the previous batch that could make things faster possibly.